# Can AWStats show bounce rate?

Tags: iis, log-files, awstats

I'm looking for a web log analyzer that can report on bounce rate.  We have used AWStats in the past as it is free and works well; however, I don't think it can report on bounce rate.

Bounce Rate - % of users who leave the site after visiting only one page.

Does it have bounce rate and I just didn't find it?  Otherwise, is there a similar system that would provide that measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Analytics**

While not technically a web log analyzer, Google Analytics provides a huge amount of valuable information... including bounce rate.

I'm a big fan of it.

Comment: Hey Thanks, sorry for the super slow response, but I do appreciate this answer.  We'll likely go this route; however, we have so many legacy sites, that adding a JS snippet to every page is unfeasible.  After we upgrade to IIS 7 (which can do it for you) we'll definitely go this route.  Thanks again!

Comment: Super slow response?  You posted your question on Sep 29th... I answered it on Sep 30th... LOL

Answer (score 0):

i searched for a bit and found:

in awstats-universe, the significant term is EXIT PAGE

so you could go on searching for a plugin which tracks if the exit-page is eqal to your home-page, which would be a bounce to my understanding.

also, you could write a plugin.

http://www.agimondo.it/extras/awstats-6.5/docs/awstats_extra.html#awredir

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_contrib.html#PLUGINS

Comment: I think the phrase "I searched for a bit" is an understatement, given how long it took you to post your response!

Comment: i didnt notice the question was that old. easy, im new here.